# display: -moz-box in Firefox, weird padding issue

Tags: jquery, firefox, css

I'm implementing a CSS3 overlay system as found on this [site](http://blog.learnboost.com/blog/a-css3-overlay-system/). My code has been slightly modified to work in Firefox however I am unable to make the box adjust its width to the content in Firefox. The following JSFiddle best represents what I am talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/MtbyW/

If you run that Fiddle within Chrome/Safari, you'll notice that the overlay box adjusts its width to fit the contents just fine, in Firefox however, a horizontal scrollbar appears.

To me it seems like the `display: -moz-box` property on `div.wrap` is causing the issue as if I remove it from the css, the content fits properly (although then I loose the vertical centering). Can someone please advise me what I am doing wrong or how to fix this within Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just played around with it and I managed to make it work on all browsers by removing the padding from the overlay_content div and adding a margin to the showme div.